# The action 'new_status' could not be found for TasksController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, action

I need help for this issue. I have Task Controller with

RESTful action and

```
private

def new_status
  @tasks.update!(active: params[:active])
  flash[:notice] = "Status update"
  redirect_to action: "index"
end
```

Have a routes

```
resources :tasks do
    get :new_status, on: :member
  end
```

But I can't change value active in database with this link

```
 <%=link_to "send data", new_status_task_path(task.id, :active => false) %>
```

In *.html.erb

```
<% @tasks.where(active: true).order(:priority).each do |task| %>
          <li class="task">
            <%= link_to task.title, task, class: "task-title text-dark" %>
            <span class="task-btn">
                <%=link_to "send data", new_status_task_path(task.id, :active => false) %>
                <%= link_to '', '', class: "fas fa-bell text-dark icon" %>
                <%= link_to '', edit_task_path(task), class:"fas fa-cogs text-dark mx-2 icon" %>
                <%= link_to '', task, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, class:"far fa-trash-alt text-dark icon" %>
            </span>
          </li>
      <% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Controller actions must be public. Move the definition of `new_status` before the `private` declaration.

```
def new_status
  @tasks.update!(active: params[:active])
  flash[:notice] = "Status update"
  redirect_to action: "index"
end

private

# rest of the controller
```